# Validate MYSQL Row (On Several Instances) Using Certain Conditions

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Throughout my server, I have several queries calling a `leads` table that use certain conditions to validate them.

```
SELECT * FROM leads WHERE user_id=3 //This line changes depending on the data needed
AND reversed!=1 AND amount>0 AND ip IS NOT NULL //These 'validation' statements are always there.

SELECT * FROM leads WHERE user_id=10 AND special_case=1
AND reversed!=1 AND amount>0 AND ip IS NOT NULL

SELECT * FROM leads WHERE user_id=15  AND special_case2=1 
AND reversed!=1 AND amount>0 AND ip IS NOT NULL
```

The second line of these queries represent validation clauses that are present on almost every query. The problem is, when I need to add another validation statement(like `AND another_column=1`), I have to edit every single query individually in my code. This takes a while and is not ideal!

What is the best best way to make a validation function that can be applied to all queries? I was thinking I could make a `$_GLOBAL` like `$validation_sql='AND reversed!=1 AND amount>0 AND ip IS NOT NULL'`, but I also thought that, maybe creating a custom MYSQL function would work better (if this can even be done).

What do you guys think? What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a view, `valid_leads`:

```
CREATE VIEW valid_leads AS
SELECT *
FROM leads
WHERE reversed!=1 AND amount>0 AND ip IS NOT NULL
```

Then you can do:

```
SELECT *
FROM valid_leads
WHERE user_id = 15 AND special_case2 = 1
```

Comment: Please excuse my inexperience, but do views update automatically when tables do?

Comment: A view is not a table, it's like a macro that gets merged into the queries that use it.

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much! So if I need to add a new condition, how would I do that? I created the view.

Comment: Drop the view and create it again with the new condition.

Comment: You should read the mysql documentation on views, as there are some limitations on how they can be used.